# Using Ember with MaskedInput and Validated Form

Tags: javascript, forms, ember.js

I want to do a form that is validated in the client side. So, I used the ember-validated form. I want to add some masks to inputs.

Is it possible to make input with validated-form and add to it a mask ?

```
{{f.input ... masked-input}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Christian has mentioned in his post `ember-validated-form` is just updated to a new release; which gives a better support for custom components. Please see the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/0491b07812bad689115bab9c786126f8?openFiles=components.masked-input-field.js%2C) to see an example of how you can use a custom masked-input component; `masked-input-field` in the twiddle; can be used. Check `application.hbs` for block-form usage of `f.input`.

In this example, I added a credit card for demonstrating masked input usage and relevant validation to `user.validation.js` in order to show how the custom masked input component (that uses [ember-cli-maskedinput](https://github.com/networkteam/ember-cli-maskedinput) underneath) respond to validations by using yielded information from `validated-input`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Within `ember-validated-form` itself, there is no support for masked imports. However, in the latest version of the addon (0.1.10, released just now), it is very easy to integrate custom components by using `f.input` in block form:

```
{{#f.input label="Favorite Color" name="color" as |fi|}}
  {{favorite-colors-component colors=colors onupdate=fi.update 
onhover=fi.setDirty}}
{{/f.input}}
```

(See [the docs](https://github.com/adfinis-sygroup/ember-validated-form#custom-input-elements) for more details)

Based on this, you should be able to integrate any addon that supports masked imports (e.g. [ember-cli-maskedinput](https://github.com/networkteam/ember-cli-maskedinput)) easily.